# Prove Euclidean norm satisfies the triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the Euclidean norm $||(s,t)||=\sqrt{s^2+t^2}$ satisfies the triangle inequality $||p+q||\le ||p||+||q||$.

I am trying to clarify what it is I am trying to prove. Is this saying that I must prove that $||(s,t)||\le ||s||+||t||$? That is $\sqrt{s^2+t^2}\le \sqrt{s^2}+\sqrt{t^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you need to prove is that $\sqrt{(s_1+s_2)^2+(t_1+t_2)^2} \le \sqrt{s_1^2+t_1^2} + \sqrt{s_2^2+t_2^2}$

Comment: should those be subtraction signs?

Comment: no but the inequality is still true with subtraction signs : that means that you replaced $s_2$ by $-s_2$ and $t_2$ by $-t_2$

Comment: So basically $||(s_1,t_1) +(s_2,t_2)||\le ||(s_1,t_1)||+||(s_2,t_2)||$

Comment: yes, you got it

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* The standard strategy is to first show that the inner product satisfies

$$\langle p, q \rangle \leq \| p \| \ \| q \|$$
for all vectors $p, q$. (This is called the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.)

Then analyze $\| p + q \|^2 = \langle p + q, p + q \rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The norm is the "size" of a *single* point in relation to an origin point.  The triangle inequality refers to the "distance" that is defined in terms of norms.  A distance is a comparison between *two* points:
$$d(x,y)
= ||x - y||
= \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2 + \ldots + (x_n + y_n)^2}.
$$

So you need to prove $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y, z)$ or

$$\sqrt{(x_1 - z_1)^2 + (x_2 - z_2)^2 + \ldots + (x_n + z_n)^2}\le \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2 + \ldots + (x_n + y_n)^2} + \sqrt{(y_1 - z_1)^2 + (y_2 - z_2)^2 + \ldots + (y_n + z_n)^2}.$$

Comment: How would one show that without using Hölder's inequality?